# Multiple searches in Ember store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to search for different records in the store.

I'm using the localStorage adapter.

But somehow the second search never finishes.

```
getUsers = this.store.find('user',{...});
getRooms = this.store.find('room',{...});

getUsers.then(function(){
   //runs
});

getRooms.then(function(){
   //doesn't run
}, function(){
   //runs, but has no arguments to check for an error.
});
```

Comment: It should run, if you get rid of the getUsers does it run?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't run? Did you try adding a failure handler to then `then`?

Comment: The failure handler of `getRooms` runs, but the arguments are undefined...

Comment: if you just do console.log(arguments) it's undefined?

Comment: Can you post the json being returned from the request, maybe the model/serializer/query if relevant?

Comment: Oh, I'm using the localStorage adapter

Comment: You might wanna try the approach proposed in the last example of this [guide page](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/persisting-records/) with that `retry` loop. You could also try to use [`rethrow`](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/blob/master/lib/rsvp/rethrow.js#L41) to see if you could catch that error.